# Multiple Magento 2 Instances on Nginx Server Duplicate Listen

Tags: magento2, nginx

I have a dev environment where I want multiple instances of Magento 2 however when adding a second site my Nginx config throws the following error on restart:

```
nginx[10338]: Nginx: [emerg] duplicate upstream "fastcgi_backend" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/magento2.com:1
```

The same Nginx config has been used on each site just pointing to separate route directories but seems to be having an issue with having duplicate upstream errors:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
server   unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name dev.magento2.com;
return 301 $scheme://dev.magento2.com$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 80 reuseport;
server_name dev.magento2.com;
set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2/public_html;

set $MAGE_MODE developer;
#set $MAGE_MODE default;
#set $MAGE_MODE production;

include /var/www/magento2/public_html/nginx.conf.sample;
fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
}
```

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream   you load upstream twice,keep it in nginx.conf

Comment: When removing the upstream directive from the virtual hosts and putting it in nginx.conf  i get another error: nginx[11502]: nginx: [emerg] "upstream" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:6

Comment: Ok i moved the upstream directive to the http section of nginx.conf and that error has stopped however now i have duplicate listen options.

Comment: This does not solve if you want different PHP versions.

Comment: you may get this resolved by moving upstream_backend directive to the default configuration file of the nginx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a simple resolution, but as far as I am aware if  you configure via `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and symlink to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` then you can only hold one version of PHP for `upstream fastcgi_backend` as this seems to be a reserved name for Magento.

I came to this 'reserved name' conclusion because when encountering this problem I renamed the upstream in my new file to `fastcgi_be` doesn't do much on my new Magento site on the same host.

Anyways maybe these lines in nginx.conf.sample (Magento 2.3.1) might help you change your upstream per-project
[image]